# Trigger a plugin before a system exception is thrown

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to enable users to force opportunity close. Therefore, I want to trigger a plugin to close quotes before a system exception is thrown.

I want to force the close of opportunity (as Lost) when quotes are still active. Therefore, I'd like to develop a plugin that will close all quotes when the use would like to close the opportunity.

The system exception that's thrown is: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1NxM.png)

I've tried several messages but all of them fail to trigger the plugin before the system exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger this plugin before the system exception is fired (in this case), register it on **Lose message** on **Opportunity entity**.

Also, remember that you can't use `context.Inputparameters["Target"]`. Instead you should use `context.InputParameters["OpportunityClose"]` and that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there 2 ways you can deal this with.

1. From Plugin, you can fire your plugin on prevalidation stage and check if all the quotes are already closed or not. But I am afraid Microsoft itself does check in prevalidation stage and hence they throw an error. But you can give it a try.
2. Now if step 1 does not work, how do we tackle this issue? I would suggest create a custom button for close opportunity. Then through this custom button fire a Plugin (action) which will check if all the active quotes are closed or not. If they are closed then call the original Microsoft (JavaScript) call which will call it's own internal plugin or so on. If not closed then you can give an alert that quotes are not yet closed and you cannot do this action.